# Using if statement on css selectors - SASS

Tags: css, sass

I am working on a stylesheet for a multisite.

I have to declare a font-size in one variable, and the variable would change depending on the selectors. Eg:

```
$newfont : 10px;
```

i am attempting this which of course is not working:

```
@if ( #header ) {
    $newfont: 30px;
}@ else if ( #footer ) {
    $newfont: 25px;
}
```

Can someone please point out what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but @if requires a SassScript expression. What you are passing is actually a selector. If you want to apply different font size for different  containers I'll suggest to use a function or mixin. For example:

```
@function get-font-size($type) {
    @if $type == "header" {
        @return 30px;
    } @else if $type == "footer" {
        @return 25px;
    }
}
#header {
    font-size: get-font-size("header");
}
#footer { 
    font-size: get-font-size("footer"); 
}
```

The code produces:

```
#header {
  font-size: 30px;
}
#footer {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

You may even control the process with a variable as you tried actually:

```
$newfontsize: 30px;
@mixin update-font-size($size) {
    $newfontsize: $size;
}
@function get-font-size() {
    @return $newfontsize;
}

#header {
    font-size: get-font-size();
}
@include update-font-size(15px);
#footer { 
    font-size: get-font-size(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry but why don't you use

```
#header{
    font-size: 30px;
}
#footer{
    font-size:25px;
}
```

and as pointed out in the comment below you can use a mixin.

Comment: I guess, because if you use this approach and you want to change those 25px to 27px you should go through all the code and substitute all the values. Using a function or a mixin is just more flexible.

Comment: But we cannot set all the values to a variable or a mixin. If font sizes are different, it's fine to put the values there. And if variables then I would do something like `$big_font: 30px; $small_font: 25px;`. Setting a value relative to a selector, it's really just plain CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to just use more variables.  This is how most theming libraries do it.

```
$header-font-size: 30px !default;
$footer-font-size: 25px !default;

#header{
    font-size: $header-font-size;
}
#footer{
    font-size: $footer-font-size;
}
```